# Lambda Function using Python Requests timing out Despite Nat Gateway

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-requests

I have a lambda function that is running a basic request in the handler. Even when running a test request to google, the requests call times out (this includes when I up the timeout period on the lambda function to 5 minutes)

Just a basic request, but here is the code. I'm using print statements to confirm that it is specifically freezing at the request. Adding a timeout to the request itself only shortens how long I need to wait until it fails.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}
    
    print('Testing requests')
    res = requests.get('https://google.com', headers=headers)
    print(res.status_code)
    print('Test complete')
```

Egress settings on security group: all CIDR ranges on all ports with all protocols
Ingress settings: Same as Egress

Subnet type: Public running through nat gateway

Function is running within a VPC.

The function works through a message sent by an SQS queue to the function. There does not seem to be an issue with that part of the functionality, so I can test it from code ran locally.

Error message:

```
[ERROR] ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcbb89d5b80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 86, in lambda_handler
    posts_res = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)
  File "/var/task/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/adapters.py", line 565, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Noting that this is happenning with multiple URLs.

Comment: "all CIDR ranges on all ports with all protocols" - def not good to hear from a security standpoint. hopefully that is a temporary thing.

Comment: plus, for this workload I would set timeout to 1 minute max honestly. no network call should take longer then that (maybe not even half that).

Comment: definitely temporary, making sure it works then will limit. Noting this is for the security group of the lambda function, not for the whole VPC

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [blog post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function) on how to configure the lambda in your VPC.  The obvious problem that I see from your description is that you are deploying the lambda in a public subnet and trying to call the NAT gateway from it.  You can only call the NAT gateway from a private subnet.

Comment: Changed it to using both a public and private subnet and we have successfully moved on to the next error :D Thank you!

Comment: LOL!  Did you post a new question?

Comment: "using both a public and private subnet" means it is going to randomly work sometimes, but not all the time. It should **only** use private subnets.